# fit along one dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a numpy array (sums_norm) of dimension (44,36) and I would like to fit all its rows with a known function. (This question is an extension of the already asked [curve fitting with a known function numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163960/curve-fitting-with-a-known-function-numpy)). I am using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,beta,p):
   return p/(4.0*np.pi)*(1+beta*(3.0/2*(np.cos(x)*np.cos(x))-1.0/2))

popt = np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),2))
pcov = np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),2))
y_fit =  np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),(sums_norm.shape[1]))) 
for i in range(0,sums_norm.shape[0],1):
   guesses = [0.2,5]
   popt[i,:],pcov[i,:] = curve_fit(func,angle_plot,sums_norm[i,:],p0=guesses)
   y_fit[i,:] =  func(angle_plot,*popt)

print popt
```

But when I run it I get the error : "could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)". What do I do wrong?
Thank you

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-315-cc50a1dcf07b> in <module>()
 29 for i in range(0,sums_norm.shape[0],1):
 30    guesses = [0.2,5]
 ---> 31    popt[i,:],pcov[i,:] = curve_fit(func,angle_plot,sums_norm[i,:],p0=guesses)
 32    y_fit[i,:] =  func(angle_plot,*popt)
```

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)

Comment: could you post in which line the error appears

Comment: Possible duplicate of the dozen other "could not broadcast" questions on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified you code with some random data, you need create `pcov` with shape `(44, 2, 2)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

sums_norm = np.random.rand(44, 36)
angle_plot = np.random.rand(36)

def func(x,beta,p):
    return p/(4.0*np.pi)*(1+beta*(3.0/2*(np.cos(x)*np.cos(x))-1.0/2))

popt = np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),2))
pcov = np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),2, 2))
y_fit =  np.zeros(((sums_norm.shape[0]),(sums_norm.shape[1]))) 
for i in range(0,sums_norm.shape[0],1):
   guesses = [0.2,5]
   popt[i,:],pcov[i,:] = curve_fit(func,angle_plot,sums_norm[i,:],p0=guesses)
   y_fit[i,:] =  func(angle_plot,*popt[i,:])

print popt
```